# Filemaker if dropdown contains text alter calculation

Tags: field, filemaker, dynamically-generated, dropdown

I am fairly sure stuff like this has been answered but I am losing my hair at the moment with this. I am using Filemaker Pro 13

I have been landed with the job of updating some templates, I have done this before but all I was doing was updating the visual side of things. Now I am wanted to dynamically update some labels and calculations depending on a 'Company selected(drop down with custom values that are all text).

Currently all costs are multiplied by 2. So if original cost = $4 then customer cost is $8. However if 'Company 4' is selected rather than being multiplied by 2 it needs to be multiplied by 1.5.

I currently have two functions that I am trying to use this functionality on a field box.

First function:

```
If (Company: = "Comp4"; 1;0)
```

Second function:

```
If (${Function1}; ${$Cost}*1.5; ${$Cost}*2 )
```

This does not work, hence the answering of this question. As far as I could understand if statements work as (Condintion; If true do X; Else do Y;). This may be the problem? I do come from a programming background but this program is irritating me beyond belief at the moment.

If this has been answered before then I offer my sincerest apologies.

Thank you for any answers or help pointing me into the right direction.

Edit: Just tried this:

```
If (ValueCount(FilterValues(Company;"Comp4"));${$Cost}*1.5; ${$Cost}*2)
```

This was to no avail. Ideally if I could fit this into one function that would be great but so far I am still failing.

Edit 2:

With regards to the function / functions not working. I would often only get the `${$Cost}*2` side of things would happen however the `${$Cost}*1.5` would not even when "Comp4" was selected. This made me think that it was either the system was not detecting "Comp4" was selected or I need to look elsewhere to find the value I need to look at.

Edit 3: Real values and calculations used

Currently used and working so to speak ( Just does the *2 aspect of things)
Field Name: `x2$Charges`
Calculation: `${$Charges}*2. - $Charges is the 'cost' fields (10 of them).`

What I want to do is when a specific company is selected rather than doing cost *2 I want to do cost *1.5.

The check for said company is :

Field Name: `x2CheckSSL`
Calculation: `If(Sales Rep.|Distributor: = "SSL";1.5;2)`

Where Sales Rep.|Distributor: is 'Company'

Comment: "*This made me think that it was either the system was not detecting "Comp4"*" That's possible. What do you get as a result of `Company = "Comp4"`? --- If you have the Advanced version, use the Data Viewer to find out, otherwise make yourself a calculation field for testing.

Comment: I created a new field which entered the text 1 or 2. When "Comp4" was selected the said text would be 1 otherwise it went to 2. However when I tried to do this with the crazy ` (Company: = "Comp4"; ${$Cost}*1.5; ${$Cost}*2 )` only the `${$Cost}*2` would apply. I am at a little bit of a loss at the moment. I am fairly sure I am looking at the right field however I can't seem to get a dynamic cost system in place. I have a feeling it is partially due to how the database was originally set up using  fields such as `$($Cost)`.

Comment: I lost you right here: "*I created a new field which entered the text 1 or 2.*" I suggest you concentrate on one point: what is the actual content of the Company field, after you have selected "Comp4" from the drop-down? I am assuming here that the field with the drop-down is named Company.

Comment: P.S. This is getting to be off-topic for SO. I suggest you join one of the Filemaker-specific forums, where you can work out the wider issue in detail.

Comment: Company field value is "SSL". I made a test field and calculation to test whether the check for "SSL" was working, to prove I was looking at the right area. Lucky for me I was using the right field for my checks. The issue is once I try the If `(Company: = "Comp4"; ${$Cost}*1.5; ${$Cost}*2 )` I only get the result I'd expect from `${$Cost}*2 `. I understand this is a little off topic now. I was hoping it was a quick small error I was making. I am updating the main post with real values as a last attempt before moving to a specialist forum.

Comment: A little bit of progress! It does the 1.5 and 2 * cost for the top field only. Edit the top field is repeated 10 times and for the rest of the boxes it applies the *2 to cost rather than the *1.5. Both Cost and Charges(the calculated field) are repeated 10 times.

Comment: This is very difficult to follow. Are you saying the Cost and Charges fields are [repeating fields](http://www.filemaker.com/help/14/fmp/en/html/create_db.8.27.html) with 10 repetitions each?

Comment: Yes both Cost and Charge fields are repeating fields. Or at least that is what I would assume. In Data -> Field 'Show repetitions' 1 to 10 (10 defined). When I do comments I accidentally press return and then feel rushed to put all of the information down, without reading through the text.

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to tell what is wrong with your syntax, because we don't know the exact names of your fields. Also, "this does not work" is not a good description of a problem.

The fact that you have constructs like `${$Cost}` indicates that you have invalid field names.

If you had fields named Company and Cost, then a calculation field (defined in the same table as these two fields) =

```
If ( Company = "Comp4" ; 1.5 ; 2 ) * Cost
```

should provide the expected result.

---

On a more general level, this is not a good approach to take. All of these factors {"Comp4", 1.5, 2} are **data** and should not be hard-coded into a calculation formula.

Properly, every company should have a markup value stored in its own record, and this would be looked up into a field when you select a company. Alternatively, only some (preferred) companies would have a markup, while others would use a default value stored in a preferences table.

In addition, the Company field in this table (Invoices?) should really be CompanyID and store only the (meaningless) ID of the selected company.

---

### Added:

This is a suggestion how to perform a quick fix to your current problem, following the clarifications made in comments.

The following fields are being assumed:

• `$Charges` - Number[10]
• `Sales Rep.|Distributor:` - Text
• `x2$Charges` - Calculation[10] = *[see formula below]*

Change the calculation formula of `x2$Charges` to =

```
If ( Extend (Sales Rep.|Distributor: ) = "SSL" ; 1.5 ; 2 ) * ${$Charges}
```

There is no need for the `x2CheckSSL` field.

**IMPORTANT:**

You should not use repeating fields for this. I suggest that as soon as possible you rewrite your solution and fix the flaws dscovered here, namely:

1. Rename your fields to valid (and reasonable*) names ;
2. Convert repeating fields to records in a related table;
3. Use lookups instead of hard-coding data in calculations.

(*) e.g. not names that end with ":"

Comment: With regards to having invalid field names, I am inclined to agree. the $($Cost) came from a previous function which just did the *2 aspect of what I am trying to accomplish. I am sorry about only putting "this does not work" I was just frustrated and forgot to better explain what was happening. Edit I have / will update the OP to further add details.

Comment: Note: Accidentally pressed return sorry. Edit I have / update the OP to further add details. With regards to not working. The `$($Cost) * 2` would apply to the correct fields however there `$($Cost)*1.5` would never trigger. Even when "Comp4" was selected. In my example I have kept out their names however I can use the real names instead? I don't have access at the moment, when I next get the chance I will try what you have typed. In the even this still doesn't work I will come back to here.

Comment: @Edward It's possible that when you select "Comp4", the actual value stored in the field is a different one. To test this, place another instance of this field on the layout, format it as Edit box and observe the contents.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. You may not realise how much I appreciate it but I do. I understand this is more of a 'Bodge' fix but for now that will do. I know the field names are horrible, I promise you when I do set variables in my case they are good names with nice ways to identify them. However sadly in this case it is an inherited database that I get to a working standard. I will make it well known that the database could do with a proper tidy up and use meaningful and valid names. Again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

IF statement works exactly as you described and I do not see why you need two different functions. I do not understand your syntax - ${$Cost}. Are you trying to add "$" to your output?

Let's say you have a field for selection as "slelect_company" in Companies table/layout and you stored cost in a variable called $cost

You calculation will be:

```
If (Companies::slelect_company = "Comp4"; $Cost*1.5; $Cost*2 )
```

If you set the field to output result, use formatting to add $ sign

If you set the label on the layout to show the output, use this:

```
If (Companies::slelect_company = "Comp4"; "$" & $Cost*1.5; "$" & $Cost*2 )
```

If you have more than one check, you can use Case - similar to switch in the other languages

Comment: "*I do not understand your syntax - ${$Cost}*" http://www.filemaker.com/help/14/fmp/en/html/create_db.8.50.html#1030956

Comment: "*Let's say you ... stored cost in a variable called $cost*" That's not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I've read your post and it is obviously the name of the field starting with $, which need an additional syntax. I am not advocating storing cost as a variable, just tried to work out where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than putting your calculation in a function try creating a new calculation field and put your calculation there.  When the record is committed you will see the value of this calculation field change and you will know if your function is working.
To do this

- Go to File->Manage->Database
- Type in a new field name and select "calculation" as the type and press create.
- Enter your calculation e.g. `if(Companies::select_company = "Comp4"; Companies::Cost * 1.5; Companies::Cost * 2)`

The calculation engine will tell you what the errors are when you try to press okay after typing the calculation.
If it never detects the condition "Comp4" then there is an error in your string comparison, perhaps a trailing space, or an uppercase character or similar.